# Creating a score variable and update it when an event occurs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have been making a random dice roll game in Flash CS5.

When a user rolls the dice, a random face is thrown and that value is added to score. The concept of the game is, the player must get 20 points in 10 tries. I didn't use external classes, instead I used the code in timeline.

The problem I have is the score is not added up and the `triesLeft` variable is not decreasing by one. After solving this problem, I need if/else statements to end the game. I would be happy if you give the code for this too.

[This is the SWF file](http://www.fastswf.com/3dLgfZI) of my project. If you need the source file I will upload it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are assigning the value of the dice roll to the score and not adding it to the score. Also it seems like you are just assigning the rolls left to 9 and not decrementing it.

Comment: i used score+=rolledNumber and i used triesLeft-- but it is not doing any good